# PostGIS ST_Difference function returns wrong geometry in result

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I'm trying to run ST_Difference but my result is incorrect
The code is here:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(
    ST_Difference(
        ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((106.694934906617 10.8530437566453, 106.694980963617 10.8529740046453, 106.695035468617 10.8528861486454, 106.695059276617 10.8528373486454, 106.695165321617 10.8526200556455, 106.695231846616 10.8524577606456, 106.695267968616 10.8523695986457, 106.695318066616 10.8522472206457, 106.695317868616 10.8522426106458, 106.695142407616 10.8521968636457, 106.694954351617 10.8521300896456, 106.694838748617 10.8520996186456, 106.694814976617 10.8521306086455, 106.694659358617 10.8521132776454, 106.694606107617 10.8524256896453, 106.694594079617 10.8524396486453, 106.694544500617 10.8526400426452, 106.694498703617 10.8528507296451, 106.694487505617 10.8528959666451, 106.694476373617 10.8529041356451, 106.694435062618 10.8529125806451, 106.694427525617 10.8529585276451, 106.694404341618 10.853118700645, 106.694370784618 10.8533247416449, 106.694437521618 10.8533458706449, 106.694721801617 10.8533875776451, 106.694733694617 10.8533889876451, 106.694934906617 10.8530437566453))'),
        ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((106.69473290032974 10.85337259541688, 106.69469456226234 10.853366656136817, 106.69473803624265 10.853260751886767, 106.69478665997649 10.853280310349916, 106.69473290032974 10.85337259541688))')
    )
)
```

Result:

```
POLYGON((106.694934906617 10.8530437566453,106.694980963617 10.8529740046453,106.695035468617 10.8528861486454,106.695059276617 10.8528373486454,106.695165321617 10.8526200556455,106.695231846616 10.8524577606456,106.695267968616 10.8523695986457,106.695318066616 10.8522472206457,106.695317868616 10.8522426106458,106.695142407616 10.8521968636457,106.694954351617 10.8521300896456,106.694838748617 10.8520996186456,106.694814976617 10.8521306086455,106.694659358617 10.8521132776454,106.694606107617 10.8524256896453,106.694594079617 10.8524396486453,106.694544500617 10.8526400426452,106.694498703617 10.8528507296451,106.694487505617 10.8528959666451,106.694476373617 10.8529041356451,106.694435062618 10.8529125806451,106.694427525617 10.8529585276451,106.694404341618 10.853118700645,106.694370784618 10.8533247416449,106.694437521618 10.8533458706449,106.694721801617 10.8533875776451,106.694733694617 10.8533889876451,106.694934906617 10.8530437566453),(106.69473290033 10.8533725954169,106.694694562262 10.8533666561368,106.694738036243 10.8532607518868,106.694786659976 10.8532803103499,106.69473290033 10.8533725954169))
```

[image]

I would like a query similar to the tools erase and intersect from ArcGIS.

[image]

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Which postgis version are you using? I've just checked it with 2.5.3 r17699 and it seems that it does the job.
SELECT 
    ST_Difference(
        ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((0 0, 10 0, 10 10, 0 10, 0 0))'),
        ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=4326;POLYGON ((1 1, 1 5, 5 5, 5 1, 1 1))')
    
);
Result
POLYGON ((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0), (1 1, 5 1, 5 5, 1 5, 1 1))

Comment: And actually, the output from your SQL seems to do not match the picture. I mean when I looked into the result string it turned out that that's actually two polygons. What tool are you using to visualize it?

Comment: What is wrong with the output? I can see two things here: 1) the input has more than 12 decimals - [enough to locate an atom](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/measuring-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude) - and the output has slightly rounded it.  2) the output polygon contains an inner ring (a hole) but it is displayed as a solid polygon

Comment: I am using postgis  3.0 and visualize my result on google map

Comment: @Vicctor picture 2 => true (export from arcgis). my result (picture 1) is wrong => the output must remove an inner polygon

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you paste WKT from ArcGis (I don't have ArcGis so far). I was mentioning picture 1 -> when I simply displayed it using Dbever, it showed a cuted out region. Perhaps there are differend flavours of WKT.